# Transition fuctions only depend on homotopy

Tags: differential-geometry, homotopy-theory, principal-bundles

I have already posted this question on the physics forum but it didn’t get any answers, hopefully here it will. In the [nLab article about Instantons](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Yang-Mills+instanton) in the section about the clutching construction, it is stated that one can construct $SU(2)$-bundles over $S^4$ via Chech cohomology choosing appropriate transition functions $g_{ij}:U_i\cap U_j \rightarrow SU(2)$ for an appropriate covering $\{U_i\}$ of $S^4$. In the article it is chosen the covering given by two open sets $U_+:=S^4\setminus${point at infinity}  and $U_-:= ${tiny neighbourhood of the point at infinity}. Later in the article it is stated than "one finds that instantons are classified by homotopy classes of maps $g:S^3\rightarrow SU(2)$" but I can't understand why. Somehow only the information about the homotopy of the intersection of the two open sets is enough. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'll begin with some general comments on the clutching construction. One can create $G$-bundles over a nice topological space $X$ through the "clutching construction". This is done by specifying the data of some $G$-bundles over an open cover $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$, that is, for each $i$ in $I$ we have a $G$-bundle $P_i\to U_i$. In order to create a global object on  $X$, we need a way to patch (or clutch) together the data we just provided. This is the data of isomorphisms $\psi_{ij}: P_i\vert_{U_i\cap U_j}\to P_{j}\vert_{U_i\cap U_j}$ which respect restriction, i.e. $\psi_{jk}\circ \psi_{ij}=\psi_{ik}$ (with the appropriate changes in domain). We then construct the total space of a $G$ bundle, via this data by $P:= (\bigsqcup_{i} P_i)/(x\sim\psi_{ij}(x))$.

If $X$ is locally contractible, i.e. it admits an open cover by contractible neighborhoods, we can take such a cover $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$. Now, the homotopy theory of $G$-bundles tells us that any $G$-bundle over a contractible set is necessarily trivial, so we can take each $P_i=U_i\times G$. This then means that each of the transition functions gives a map $U_{i}\cap U_j\to G$ (automorphisms of a trivial $G$-bundle are given by $(u, g)\mapsto (u, \phi(u)g)$). Any homotopy of clutching functions $\{\psi_{ij}^t\}_{i,j\in I^2}$, meaning a smoothly varying collection of functions $\psi_{ij}^t: U_{i}\cap U_{j}\to G$ which satisfy $\psi_{jk}^t \psi_{ij}^t=\psi_{ik}^t$ for all $t$, determine a vector bundle $E_t$ over $[0,1]\times X$ since the $\{[0,1]\times U_i\}$ forms an open cover for $[0,1]\times X$. Since $[0,1]$ is contractible, it follows that the restrictions $E_t\vert_{\{0\}\times X}$ and $E_t\vert_{\{1\}\times X}$ are isomorphic as vector bundles over $X$. By construction, $E_{t}\vert_{\{\tau\}\times X}$ is the bundle that we get by taking the clutching functions $\{\psi_{ij}^\tau\}$ for fixed $\tau$.

Now we turn our attention to the sphere. Let $P\to S^n$ be a principal $G$ bundle. We can cover $S^n$ by the open sets $U^{\pm}=S^n\backslash{(\pm 1, 0, 0,\cdots, 0)}$, which are diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ via stereographic projection and are hence contractible. Since this cover has no triple intersections, we do not have to verify any cocycle condition and we may conclude that any principal $G$-bundle over $S^n$ is gotten by specifying clutching functions $\psi_{+-}: U^+\cap U^-\to G$ and any homotopic map yields an isomorphic $G$-bundle. Because the intersection $U^+\cap U^-$ deformation retracts to the equatorial $S^{n-1}$ of $S^n$, all homotopy classes of maps $U^+\cap U^-\to G$ are represented by a map $S^{n-1}\to G$. The retraction $p:U^+\cap U^-\to S^{n-1}$ is given by $(x_0, x_1,\cdots, x_n)\mapsto \frac{1}{\sum x_i^2}(x_1, \cdots, x_n)$ so we may produce the proper clutching function by taking $\tilde{f}=f\circ p: U^+\cap U^-\to G$. $$\tilde{f}(x_0, \cdots, x_n)=f\left(\frac{x_1}{\sum_{i} x_i^2}, \frac{x_2}{\sum_{i} x_i^2}, \cdots, \frac{x_n}{\sum_{i} x_i^2}\right)$$